# I found a theorem? Is this consistent with the change of variables formula?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a ${C}^{\infty}$ function defined on ${\mathbb{R}}^{2} $.
I considered the following function, $G$ and I probably found the following Theorem. However, I feel that something is wrong.

$G(t,s):={\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} f({u}_{1}\textbf{a}+{u}_{2}\textbf{b})\ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}$

---

> **Theorem?**
>
> Let $f:{\mathbb{R}}^{2}\to {\mathbb{R}}$ be ${C}^{\infty}$ function, $\textbf{a},\textbf{b}\in {\mathbb{R}}^{2}$:
>   These are linearly independent, $t,s\in\mathbb{R}$, and G and g are defined as follows.
>
> $\ \ g(t,s):=f(t\textbf{a} + s\textbf{b})$ 
>   $\ \ G(t,s):={\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} f({u}_{1}\textbf{a}+{u}_{2}\textbf{b})\ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}$
>   Then,
>
> $\ $(1)$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial t\partial s}(t,s)=f(t\textbf{a}+s\textbf{b})$
>
> $\ $(2)$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t\partial s}(t,s)={}^{T}\textbf{a}(Hf)_{(t\textbf{a}+s\textbf{b})}\textbf{b}$
>
> $\ $(3)$f(t\textbf{a} + s\textbf{b})={\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} 
> \ {}^{T}\textbf{a}(Hf)_{({u}_{1}\textbf{a}+{u}_{2}\textbf{b})}\textbf{b}
> \ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}$
>
> Here, ${}^{T}\textbf{a}$ is the 
>   Transpose vector of $\textbf{a}$ , and $(Hf)$ is Hessian matrix of $f$ .

---

**Proof of (1)?**

$G(t,s)={\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} g({u}_{1},{u}_{2})\ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}$

and, according to Fubini's theorem, the following is correct:

$$g(t,s)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t\partial s}{\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} g({u}_{1},{u}_{2})\ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}
=\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial t\partial s}(t,s)
,$$ and 
$g(t,s):=f(t\textbf{a} + s\textbf{b})$. Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial t\partial s}(t,s)=f(t\textbf{a} + s\textbf{b}).$$

**Proof of (2)?**

$$\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{t}}(t,s)
= \left\langle gradf(t\textbf{a}+s\textbf{b})|\textbf{a}\right\rangle,
$$ 
and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} (gradf(t\textbf{a}+s\textbf{b}))
=(\frac{\partial gradf}{\partial x}(t\textbf{a}+s\textbf{b}),
\frac{\partial gradf}{\partial y}(t\textbf{a}+s\textbf{b})
)\cdot\textbf{b}
=(Hf)_{(t\textbf{a}+s\textbf{b})}\cdot\textbf{b}.
$$ 
Here, $gradf$ is the gradient vector of $f$, and 
$\left\langle \ \ |\ \ \right\rangle$ is dot product of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t\partial s}(t,s)={}^{T}\textbf{a}(Hf)_{(t\textbf{a}+s\textbf{b})}\textbf{b}\ \ $$■

**Proof of (3)?**

Differentiate both sides of the following expression.
$$G(t,s)={\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} g({u}_{1},{u}_{2})\ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}$$

Differentiation and integration are interchangeable. Therefore, considering (2)
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t\partial s}G(t,s)
=\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t\partial s}{\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} g({u}_{1},{u}_{2})\ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}$$
$$={\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t\partial s}g({u}_{1},{u}_{2})\ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}={\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} 
\ {}^{T}\textbf{a}(Hf)_{({u}_{1}\textbf{a}+{u}_{2}\textbf{b})}\textbf{b}
\ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}$$

On the other hand, considering (1), The left side of the above formula is:
$$f(t\textbf{a} + s\textbf{b}) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t\partial s}G(t,s)$$

Therefore,
$$f(t\textbf{a} + s\textbf{b}) 
={\int}_{{{u}_{2}}=0}^{{{u}_{2}}=s}{\int}_{{{u}_{1}}=0}^{{{u}_{1}}=t} 
\ {}^{T}\textbf{a}(Hf)_{({u}_{1}\textbf{a}+{u}_{2}\textbf{b})}\textbf{b}
\ d{u}_{1}d{u}_{2}$$   ■

---

> **My question**
>
>   Are these Theorem? (1)-(3) correct? If it is correct, is it consistent with the variable conversion formula?

**P.S.**
I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions.

Comment: I've edited to make your question more readable. Using `<br>` makes it really tough to look at. I hope I didn't change the meaning in any way.

Comment: @John Hughes:Thank you for your editing. Thanks to that, it became easier to  read.

Comment: The first two are correct, but the last one isn't. Just take $f(s,t) = s+t$. Then $Hf = 0$ and so $a^T(Hf)b = 0$, while $f(s,t)\neq 0$.

Comment: @amsmath: Thanks for your comment. Certainly, the example you taught me seems to be a counterexample of (3). Even if an integration constant is added to (3), the problem is not likely to be removed.

Comment: @amsmath:However, if (1) and (2) are correct, (3) seems obvious.  
Are differentiations and integrations not exchangeable?
So, I am so confused.

Comment: Later, I will write more about the 'proof' of (3). It will be helpful to identify what my misunderstandings are.

Comment: I added detailed descriptions to Proof 3. Please let me know where is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that differentiation and integration only interchange when the boundaries of the integral do not depend on the variable with respect to which you are differentiating. In the easiest case of dependency, namely $\int_0^t$, we have
$$
\frac d{dt}\int_0^t\phi(s)\,ds = \phi(t), \quad\text{while}\quad\int_0^t\phi'(s)\,ds = \phi(t)-\phi(0).
$$
Hence,
$$
G_{ts}(t,s) = \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_0^s\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^tg(u,v)\,du\,dv = \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_0^sg(t,v)\,dv = g(t,s),
$$
which is  (1). From the first line above we also get $\frac d{dt}\int_0^t\phi(s)\,ds = \phi(t) = \phi(0) + \int_0^t\phi'(s)\,ds$. Using this twice, we obtain
\begin{align*}
G_{ts}(t,s)
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_0^s\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^tg(u,v)\,du\,dv = \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_0^s\left(g(0,v)+\int_0^tg_t(u,v)\,du\right)\,dv\\
&= g(0,0) + \int_0^tg_t(u,0)\,du + \int_0^s\left(g_s(0,v) + \int_0^tg_{st}(u,v)\,du\right)\,dv\\
&= g(0,0) + \int_0^tg_t(u,0)\,du + \int_0^s g_s(0,v)\,dv + \int_0^s\int_0^tg_{st}(u,v)\,du\,dv.
\end{align*}
The rightmost summand is your term with the Hessian. Now, $g(t,s) = f(ta+sb)$, hence $g_t(t,s) = f'(ta+sb)a$, so that $g_t(u,0) = f'(ua)a = \phi'(u)$, where $\phi(u) = f(ua)$. Therefore, $\int_0^tg_t(u,0)\,du = \phi(t)-\phi(0) = f(ta)-f(0,0)$. Similarly, $\int_0^s g_s(0,v)\,dv = f(sb)-f(0,0)$. So, you get

> $$ f(ta+sb) = f(ta)+f(sb)-f(0,0) + \int_0^s\int_0^t a^TH_f(ua+vb)b\,du\,dv. $$

Let's check this with an example. Let $a=(1,1)^T$ and $b=(1,-1)^T$ and $f(x,y) = x^2 + xy^2$ (random choice ;-)). Then
$$
f(ta+sb) = f((t,t)+(s,-s)) = f(t+s,t-s) = (t+s)^2+(t+s)(t-s)^2.
$$
The Hessian of $f$ is
$$
H_f(x,y) = 2\begin{pmatrix}1&y\\y&x\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence,
$$
a^TH_f(ua+vb)b = 2(1,1)\begin{pmatrix}1&u-v\\u-v&u+v\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix} = 2(1-u-v).
$$
Integrating this over $[0,t]\times [0,s]$ gives $2ts-t^2s-ts^2$. Moreover,
$$
f(ta)+f(sb)-f(0,0) = t^2+t^3+s^2+s^3.
$$
Now, it is not difficult to see that
$$
t^2+t^3+s^2+s^3 + 2ts-t^2s-ts^2 = (t+s)^2+(t+s)(t-s)^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood it completely. You are great! !

Comment: Thank you very much, Blue Various.